# page break issue with tcolorbox's height fixed for

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, tcolorbox

When using the `height fixed for=first and middle` option on a `tcolorbox`, the page break behavior becomes awkward.

Try uncommenting the identified line in the following MWE to see what happens.

Interestingly enough, the issue does not arise if the `attach boxed title to top left` option is commented out. This seems to indicate that `tcolorbox` is having trouble calculating the available remaining height when using a `boxed title`. Perhaps the box's height and/or frame height aren't taken into account for this calculation (possible `tcolorbox` bug?)...

Does anybody have a fix for this? I would really like to have the `first` and `middle` boxes vertically fill the page while keeping a somewhat "normal" page break behavior.

All packages have been updated on my computer today, but the issue was happening with previous versions.

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{%
  contourskin/.style={%
      enhanced,
      breakable,
      frame hidden,
      %height fixed for=first and middle,%% <-- This causes the issue!
      parbox=false,
      colback=white,
      attach boxed title to top left={xshift=12pt},%% <-- Issue does not occur if this line is commented...
      boxed title style={enhanced,top=4pt,left=12pt,right=12pt,
          frame hidden,
          interior style={left color=blue!20,right color=white},
          overlay={%
              \draw[blue!60,line width=2pt]
                  ([xshift=-.5em,yshift=-1pt]frame.north west)--([xshift=.5em,yshift=-1pt]frame.north east);%
          }%
      },
      coltitle=blue!60!black,
      fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
      before skip=\baselineskip,
      left=12pt,
      top=.8em,
      drop large lifted shadow,
      underlay unbroken={%
          \coordinate (coin) at (title.north-|frame.west); 
          \draw[blue!60,line width=1pt] ([yshift=-1pt]title.north east) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=-1pt]coin) -- +(0,-1.2cm);
          \draw[blue!60,line width=2pt] ([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=-1pt-1.2cm]coin) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);
          \draw[blue!60,line width=2pt] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west) -- (frame.south east);%
      },
      underlay first={%
          \coordinate (coin) at (title.north-|frame.west); 
          \draw[blue!60,line width=1pt] ([yshift=-1pt]title.north east) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=-1pt]coin) -- +(0,-1.2cm);
          \draw[blue!60,line width=2pt] ([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=-1pt-1.2cm]coin) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);
      },
      underlay middle={%
          \draw[blue!60,line width=2pt] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);%
      },
      underlay last={%
          \draw[blue!60,line width=2pt] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);
          \draw[blue!60,line width=2pt] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west) -- (frame.south east);%
      },%
  },
}

\newtcolorbox{mycontourbox}[1][]{contourskin,#1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{mycontourbox}[title={Example}]
  \lipsum[4]
  \lipsum[4]
  \lipsum[4]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{mycontourbox}

\end{document}
```

---

**Output with `height fixed for` line commented**:

[image: Output with <code>height fixed for</code> line commented]

**Output with `height fixed for` line uncommented**:

[image: Output with <code>height fixed for</code> line uncommented]

**Output with `attach boxed title to top left` line commented**:

[image: Output with <code>attach boxed title to top left</code> line commented]

Comment: I can confirm this problem on my system. In a few hours, I will have time to look for the cause of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `tcolorbox version 3.72 (2015/08/12)` (and higher) do not have this
>   problem. The following patch can be used for older versions.

This is a bug of `tcolorbox` which only appears by combining `height fixed for` or `height fill` with bounding box changes. Internally, a `boxed title` changes the bounding box to comprise this detached title.

The following patch corrects this bug by taking the bounding box alterations into some of the height calculations. This patch works for `tcolorbox` version `3.71 (2015/07/23)` and should also work for several older versions down to `3.35 (2015/01/07)` or so.

```
% ......

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins}

\makeatletter

\def\tcb@height@fill@unbroken#1{%
  \tcb@prepare@break@operation%
  \tcb@breakat@init%
  \tcbset{compress page=#1}%
  \tcb@comp@h@page%
  \tcbset{height=\tcb@h@page-\kvtcb@bbtop@stand-\kvtcb@bbbottom@stand,after=\eject}%
}

\def\tcb@break@ch@fixed{%
  \ifdim\tcb@natheight<\tcb@h@page\relax%
    \tcbdimto\kvtcb@height@fixed{\tcb@h@page-\kvtcb@bbtop-\kvtcb@bbbottom}%
    \tcb@ch@fixed%
  \else%
    \tcb@ch@natural%
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

% ......
```

This patch will be integrated into the next `tcolorbox` version `3.72` (or higher). This bug fixing version will appear soon.